# Может ли один javascript подгрузить другой?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Например на странице есть один javascript. После загрузки страницы, он подгружает другие скрипты по известным адресам?

Можно ли такое сделать и как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Answer (score 0):

Есть так же популярная библиотека для динамического подключения модулей [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)